# How do I do live display of a log file from FTP server?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, updates, viewer

I have a device that logs movement with a sensor and (via PHP) sends the log file to the FTP server every 10 seconds. The device essentially POSTs a message to a PHP script which then modifies the file on the FTP server.

I want to monitor the logging without having to reopen the file again and again.

This shouldn't really be too hard to code, just refresh the content of the file every time there's a request to the server. Is there way to update, say, Notepad++ every time the file changes? My Google searches have not been successful.

Comment: There's no "POST" request in FTP. So, does the device upload the log by HTTP POST or does it really upload by FTP (but by FTP STOR request)?

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here. So if you want  to avoid your question being closed, reword it to ask for a solution, not a software. I.e. *"How do I do live display of a log file from FTP server?"*

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention: The POST request is sent to a php script which then writes the POST data into the file on the FTP.

Comment: I used your suggestion to update the title, I hope it won't get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WinSCP` with [Directory Synchronization](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full) option. There is `synchronize` script which will make it automatic. Check the [Automate file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP server or SFTP server](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) guide.

Then Notepad++ should notify about changes made in file automaticly. The option you're probably looking is disabling the confirmation which can be found in `Settings -> Preferences -> MISC -> Update silently`.

There is also [DocMonitor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/DocMonitor/) plugin for Notepad++.

> Document updater updates your opened documents in Notepad++ every 3 seconds

You can find it in `Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager` as `Document Monitor`.

Comment: Keep up to date function is for "local to remote" direction. I believe that OP is asking for "remote to local".

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You're right. I've edited my answer to the correct option.

Comment: Alright, I installed WinSCP and the Directory Synchronization is working. I'm just clueless how to execute a script to do the synchronization for me. Help please? I tried running a "winscp.com /script=myscript.txt" command in my CMD, but the command is not recognized..